# On click, how to make audio play all the way through?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, onclick, html5-audio

So I have an image, that when I click it I want it to play all the way through. When I click the image once it plays through, but I want to make it so when people that spam click it, it only plays once and that plays all the way through before restarting the audio.

Here is my javascript:

```
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function playSound(soundfile) {
  document.getElementById("img").innerHTML=document.getElementById("img").innerHTML +
    "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
    }
        </script>
```

Here is my html:

```
<span id="img" onclick="playSound('assets/audio.mp3');">
    <img src="assets/img.jpg" name="img" width="350" height="350" border="0" id="img" />
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if HTML5, you can maintain an audio object check the status and reject request if already in playing mode:

```
var audio = new Audio();

function playSound(soundfile) {
  if(!audio.paused) return;
  audio.src = soundfile;
  audio.play();
}
```